# python code that implements LU decomposition I found the following

Tags: python, numerical-methods

In my search for a python code that implements LU decomposition I found the following. I have two questions:

1. I am wondering if this code uses partial pivoting or not; I am
   looking for one that does not use partial pivoting.
2. When I run this code, I get the following errors:

Traceback:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-88eb5f3643e3> in <module>()
 60 
 61 A = [[7, 3, -1, 2], [3, 8, 1, -4], [-1, 1, 4, -1], [2, -4, -1, 6]]
---> 62 P, L, U = lu_decomposition(A)
 63 
 64 print ("A:")

<ipython-input-13-88eb5f3643e3> in lu_decomposition(A)
 54         for i in range(j, n):
 55             s2 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(j))
---> 56             L[i][j] = (PA[i][j] - s2) / U[j][j]
 57 
 58     return (P, L, U)

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

And here is the code I am using

```
import numpy as np
import pprint

def mult_matrix(M, N):
    """Multiply square matrices of same dimension M and N"""

    # Converts N into a list of tuples of columns                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    tuple_N = zip(*N)

    # Nested list comprehension to calculate matrix multiplication                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return [[sum(el_m * el_n for el_m, el_n in zip(row_m, col_n)) for col_n in tuple_N] for row_m in M]

def pivot_matrix(M):
    """Returns the pivoting matrix for M, used in Doolittle's method."""
    m = len(M)

    # Create an identity matrix, with floating point values                                                                                                                                                                                            
    id_mat = [[float(i ==j) for i in range(m)] for j in range(m)]

    # Rearrange the identity matrix such that the largest element of                                                                                                                                                                                   
    # each column of M is placed on the diagonal of of M                                                                                                                                                                                               
    for j in range(m):
        row = max(range(j, m), key=lambda i: abs(M[i][j]))
        if j != row:
            # Swap the rows                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            id_mat[j], id_mat[row] = id_mat[row], id_mat[j]

    return id_mat

def lu_decomposition(A):
    """Performs an LU Decomposition of A (which must be     square)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    into PA = LU. The function returns P, L and U."""
    n = len(A)

    # Create zero matrices for L and U                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    L = [[0.0] * n for i in range(n)]
    U = [[0.0] * n for i in range(n)]

    # Create the pivot matrix P and the multipled matrix PA                                                                                                                                                                                            
    P = pivot_matrix(A)
    PA = mult_matrix(P, A)

    # Perform the LU Decomposition                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    for j in range(n):
    # All diagonal entries of L are set to unity                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        L[j][j] = 1.0

        # LaTeX: u_{ij} = a_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} u_{kj} l_{ik}                                                                                                                                                                                      
        for i in range(j+1):
            s1 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(i))
            U[i][j] = PA[i][j] - s1

        # LaTeX: l_{ij} = \frac{1}{u_{jj}} (a_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} u_{kj} l_{ik} )                                                                                                                                                                  
        for i in range(j, n):
            s2 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(j))
            L[i][j] = (PA[i][j] - s2) / U[j][j]

    return (P, L, U)


A = [[7, 3, -1, 2], [3, 8, 1, -4], [-1, 1, 4, -1], [2, -4, -1, 6]]
P, L, U = lu_decomposition(A)

print ("A:")
pprint.pprint(A)
print ("P:")
pprint.pprint(P)

print ("L:")
pprint.pprint(L)

print ("U:")
pprint.pprint(U)
```

Comment: Please remember that SO limits you to one topic per posted question.  Your algorithm question would have to be a separate question, and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obvious with a little diagnostic use of `print`:

```
    for i in range(j, n):
        s2 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(j))
        print("size PA:", len(PA), len(PA[i]), i, j)
        print("PA", PA[i][j])
        print("size L :", len(L),  len(L[i]),  i, j)
        print("L",  L[i][j])
        print("size U :", len(U),  len(U[i]),  i, j)
        print("U",  U[j][i])
        L[i][j] = (PA[i][j] - s2) / U[j][j]
```

Output:

```
size PA: 4 4 0 0
PA 7.0
size L : 4 4 0 0
L 1.0
size U : 4 4 0 0
U 7.0
size PA: 4 0 1 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 68, in <module>
    P, L, U = lu_decomposition(A)
  File "so.py", line 57, in lu_decomposition
    print("PA", PA[i][j])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You get to a point where `PA` has 4 rows, but the first row is empty.  You cannot index location 0 of an empty list.

As for fixing the problem, you need to diagnose just how the algorithm works, and where you implementation fails to match the given algorithm.  I, for one, am not going to reverse-engineer the algorithm from code that is barely documented and deals in one- and two-letter abbreviations for anonymous concepts.  As the posting guidelines tell you, make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: thanks for your post. So there is no quick fix to fix this code you can tell me?

Comment: Nope.  "fix" requires knowing how that code block is *supposed* to operate, and how the inputs got to their current states.